# Oracle UDT with EntityFramework Support

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, devart, dotconnect

is there any support for oracle user defined data types with Entityframework 5 or 6 (devart dotConnect or ODP.Net) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework supports only primitive types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832.aspx) and doesn't support user-defined types (UDT).

We recommend you to work with UDT via plain ADO.NET: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Objects.html .

As for the ODP.NET, please refer to Oracle support with this question: https://community.oracle.com/community/developer/english/oracle_database/windows_and_.net/odp.net

Comment: Hello, is this is supported in EF Core or not?

Comment: UDTs in EF Core via dotConnect for Oracle are not supported.